# Any interactive ODE environments like "Slopes" but for PC?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software

On my iPad I enjoy using [the free Slopes app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/slopes-differential-equations/id1136920301) which allows you to just open the app, click "system", put in a system of ODE without any programming, and you immediately get plots and a slope field. It is very useful to have a thought, write down the ODE immediately and then immediately see the behavior of systems. But I haven't found anything like this for PC. Of course I know there's Maple, Matlab, Mathematica, Excel, the Jupyter/Sympy/SciPy/Matplotlib stack, and something similar for R, but they all require writing at least a few lines of code that need to be looked up just to get something going, really requiring a context switch between having an idea and exploring that idea. Is there anything like it on PC?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://safeforpc.com/slope-for-pc-windows-and-mac-free-download

Comment: @trula No unfortunately that is about an unrelated game called "Slope". There is also an unrelated iOS app called "Slopes" about skiing. But I linked to the version of Slopes I am referring to.

Comment: It seems you have to install a android emulator to use slope on your PC, https://napkforpc.com/app/EK53V9847R.com.lucas.slopes/slopes-differential-equations/

Comment: @trula I was really hoping for help finding something built natively for a PC environment that is *like* Slopes, not necessarily running exactly the Slopes program on an emulator, but thanks I will try it if there are no solutions native to PC.

Comment: In ye olden days when Java applets were still a thing there was an expression parser producing expression trees that was used to produce phase portraits with nullclines and direction fields for 2D autonomous systems. If you know the file structure of java and how to compile a java project you can still extract this program from https://labs.ni.gsu.edu/ashilnikov/software/newphase/newphase.html starting with https://labs.ni.gsu.edu/ashilnikov/software/newphase/newphase.class (for some reason the directory is not viewable.) Or get it from https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/phase/